# Assist with using native html form in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

[image]Hello:  I have done tons of html forms in wordpress and am now trying to do the same in laravel.  The problem is with submitting the form; it is not going to my destination or passing the post variables as I would expect.  (i am getting errors on the loading of the page).

- I know it has something to do with the "routes" and possibly also CSRF?  (been reading a lot on this and seeing all kinds of info
- I have seen things about using Laravel to build a form "open form/close form" but I am trying to find a way to just use an html form
- I have the default laravel installed with nothing extra...
- I tried adding a "post" route but that did not help...

here is what i have now:

this is from my routes.php file:

```
 Route::post('gz_form', ['as' => 'gz_form', 'uses' => 'cont15_gzap@gzap_cont_function']);
```

here is the top of my form:

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="off"  action="{{ route('gz_form') }}" >

<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>


 <input type="hidden" name="gc_post" value=2 />
```

(I threw on that token input as some people suggested that...)

Anyway - I am hoping someone can help me with this...

[image]

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: OK i edited the question and added a screen shot of the errors - i hope that helps...

Comment: Shouldn't be a CSRF problem. Can you check that it's posting to the correct URL ('gz_form')? What's the URL when you get this error?

Comment: here is the url (changed domain):  http://example.com/%7B%7B%20route('gz_form')%20%7D%7D

Comment: Well there's your problem. Try replacing `action="{{ route('gz_form') }}"` with `action="/gz_form"`. Not long-term solution, but at least you'll see if the form and routes are working correctly.

Comment: On a second thought, what's the name of your view file (the one that has the form)? Double check that it ends with `.blade.php`. It doesn't seem to be parsing blade syntax.

Comment: actually it is a php file included within the view file; the view file has all the proper name; but the included file is just a ".php" file....

Comment: oh and when i made that change you suggested - it did get rid of the "not found" but then it said stuff about csrf error...

Comment: Then the problem is that some of your view files are not ending with `.blade.php`. Because the `{{ csrf_token() }}` will also not parse correctly (you can check the source and see for yourself). Make sure your views end with `.blade.php` and it will all work (also change back to `{{ route('gz_form') }}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using both of your inputs - but once i had it down to the token mismatch - i finally got it to work by changing the input on my form to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
```

i found that somewhere and by doing that the token mismatch went away...

But thanks for your help guys - getting this to work took more than one step and so your help was needed and helpful...

Answer (score 2):

you have to check your route method .. is it post or get .. and check if your route named already or not ..

```
Route::post('/gz_form', 'YourController@handler')->name('gz_form');
```

while you using `{{ route('gz_form') }}` you need to name it

Comment: He did name it. `['as' => 'gz_form']` will do the same as `->name('gz_form')`

Comment: Had to step away for a bit - but anyway; renamed my include file to end with ".blade.php"; and I tried the "action" part of my form both ways; but now am getting a token mismatch error; i will post a pic